# $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ uncorrelated $|X_k|<52\ \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. Show $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k]\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}}0$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, law-of-large-numbers

*Not a homework question but an exercise from an past exam.*

> Let $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be uncorrelated real valued random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}$ and fulfilling $|X_k|<52$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
>   Show that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k]\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{\mathbb{P}}0$$ (convergence in probability).

I attempted to use the following theorem from the lecture:

> **Theorem (Generalisation of the Weak Law of Large Numbers)**
>   Let $(X_k)_{k = 1}^{n}$ be pairwisely uncorrelated with finite variance.
>   Then 
>   $$
> \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \text{Var}[X_k]
> \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
> $$
>   implies
>   $$
> \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \left( X_k - \mathbb{E}[X_k] \right)
> \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{\mathbb{P}} 0.
> $$

**My progress**
By definition we have
$$
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \text{Var}[X_k]
\overset{\textrm{Def.}}{=} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[(X_k - \mathbb{E}[X_k])^2]
\le \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} 2 \cdot 52 
\le \frac{1}{n^2} 2n \cdot 52
= \frac{104}{n}
\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: $|X_k-\mathbb E[X_k]|<2\times 52=104$ so $\mathbb E[(X_k-\mathbb E[X_k])^2] <104^2$. You just forgot about the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Feng Shao, the only minor mistake is that you forgot the squares in bounding $\mathbb E[(X_k-\mathbb E[X_k])^2] $.

In order to save some efforts, we could also assume without loss of generality that $\left\lvert X_k\right\rvert<1$ (work with $X'_i=X_i/52$).